# AngularJS : how to hide and show list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I make a demo of filter.It is working fine.Now I need to make autocomplete with same code or logic .My list is display whole time when I run the project.I need to show list when user enter text in input field.when user remove all text from the input field it hide again list.as same as autocomple or autosuggest in jquery ? can we implement in angular ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-rc2" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="cnt">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchText.category">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat= "a in d.obj | filter:searchText">
                   <td> {{a.name}} </td>
                <td> {{a.category}} </td>


            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
<script>
  var app=angular.module("myapp",[]);
app.factory('data',function(){
    var data={};
    data.obj=[
        {"name": "Apple", category: "Apple"},
        {"name": "bb", category: "Frui"}     ,
        {"name": "df", category: "Apple"}    ,
        {"name": "sds", category: "Frui"}


    ]


    return data;
});

function cnt($scope,data){
    $scope.d=data;
   // alert('-'+$scope.d.obj)

}
</script>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid displaying the table something when `searchText.category` is undefined or empty:

```
<table ng-show="searchText.category && searchText.category.length != 0">
```

or

```
<table ng-if="searchText.category && searchText.category.length != 0">
```